# UITableView "cellForRowAt: indexPath" Occasionally Calling "init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)" on Core Data Attribute

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, transformable

I have a core data entity `Person` with a transformable attribute `age` of type `Age`.

```
final class Person: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public fileprivate(set) var age: Age
}
```

`Age` adopts the `NSCoding` protocol and has two variables `value` and `scale`, but only the `value` is saved:

```
class Age: NSObject, NSCoding {

    @objc public var value: Double
    public var scale = 1.0

    override public var description: String {
        return "\(scale * value)"
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(value, forKey: #keyPath(value))
    }

    public convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init(value: aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: #keyPath(value)))
    }

    init(value: Double) {
        self.value = value
    }

}
```

I display the `age` of an instance of `Person` within a `UITableViewCell`. This instance (`person`) has an age value of 10.0, i.e. `person.age.value = 10.0`, such that when the scale is changed programatically to say `scale = 2.0` via a `UIStepper`, the `UITableViewCell` displays `20.0` (i.e. `scale * value`).

**However**, I'm finding that if I increment the `UIStepper` enough times eventually the initialisation of the `Age` class for the `Person` is called during the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method, which returns an instance of `Person` at a given `IndexPath`. This obviously causes the `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method within the `Age` class to be called, which resets the value of the `scale` property to 1.

**Why does this happen, please, and is there a way fixed this at all?** I ideally want the value of the `scale` property to always remain what it is set to on the `UIStepper`.

Thanks for any help on this matter.

**EDIT**

A given `person` at an `indexPath` is obtained in the following way:

```
private var people: [Person] {
    return Array(database.people).sortedArray(using: Person.defaultSortDescriptors)
}

private func person(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Person {
    return people[indexPath.item]
}
```

Comment: `This obviously causes the init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) method within the Age class to be called`: With what coder is Age being initialized? I don‘t see how transformable fits in here. Is it about persisting Age and if a cell is reloaded the scale is lost? Was the coder supposed to store/persist the Age every time the UIStepper changes and on reload/later supply the wanted value to the Age?

Comment: How do you get the array of persons? Can you provide a source code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method? The initialisation of the `age` property may be caused by turning your `Person` object into fault. Further access to the `age` property will restore it from the storage by `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`.

Comment: @cocavo Thanks for your help. I have included how the `person` is selected from an set of `People` stored in a `Database` entity.

Comment: As I understood the `people` array is generated every time you access it. This is why you are getting a newly created `Person` object within `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Try to generate the `people` array only once and store it as a property of view controller. I guess it should help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `people` property is a [computed property](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID259), which means you get a new people array every time you access it by `people[indexPath.item]`. So you are initializing a new Person instance every time you call `func person(at:)`, which I guess in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`.

Test this by changing the stepper value, and then make the cell disappear from the screen and come back to the same cell. Then the age will have been reset.

Just make your people array a stored property like this.

```
private var people: [Person] = Array(database.people).sortedArray(using: Person.defaultSortDescriptors)
```